# 'C:\Users\name' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

when I tried to install sklearn_extra in Jupyter notebook

```
pip install scikit-learn-extra
```

I get this message as an output

> 'C:\Users\name' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

how can I solve this

Comment: Can you share what the name actually is? Is that all the output?

Answer (score 0):

Install a package in a Jupyter notebook as follows.

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install scikit-learn-extra
```

Read [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook) for more information.

Comment: same problem      'C:\Users\name' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

I hope I answered on time, I had a similar problem and what fixed it was removing all the spacebars in your direcotry path as the command promt reads it as two different commands:
[Here i had to delete the spacebar in the name of the file from Diskretni signali to Diskretni_signali and then it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKm6H.png)

Comment: my guess is you have: 'C:\Users\firstname lastname' try changing it to 'C:\Users\firstname_lastname' or change the installation folder of python.exe